# How to mix IF and CASE in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I have a table like this

| field_one | field_two | field_three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | null | 3 |
| A | null | null |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | null | 4 |
| B | null | null |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| C | null | null |

I'd like to select a new field using this logic. (I wrote it in JS stytle for understanding.):

```
new_field = field_two

if ( field_two == null ) {
   new_field = field_three
}

if ( field_three == null ) {
   switch ( field_one ) {
       case 'A':
           new_field = 100
       case 'B':
           new_field = 200
       case 'C':
           new_field = 300
   }
}
```

Expected result:

| field_one | field_two | field_three | new_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| A | null | 3 | 3 |
| A | null | null | 100 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | null | 4 | 4 |
| B | null | null | 200 |
| C | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| C | null | null | 300 |

Can I do this in a query in BigQuery??

I know COALESCE and CASE but not enough for the above logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select 
    *,
    coalesce(field_two, 
             field_three,
             case field_one when "A" then 100 when "B" then 200 when "C" then 300 END) as new_field
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using this select, assuming you just want to *view* the column `new_field`:

```sql
SELECT field_one, field_two, field_three,
       COALESCE(field_two,
                field_three,
                CASE field_one WHEN 'A' THEN 100
                               WHEN 'B' THEN 200
                               WHEN 'C' THEN 300 END)) AS new_field
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY field_one, field_two, field_three;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `IF` is usually represented as `CASE`. Use a simple nested `CASE` for your problem

```
   Select field_one,    field_two,  field_three, 
   Case when field_two is NULL
   THEN field_three
   When field_three is NULL
   THEN 
            CASE WHEN FIELD_ONE ='A' 
            Then 100
            WHEN FIELD_ONE ='B' 
            Then 200
            WHEN FIELD_ONE ='C' 
            Then 300
            END
   END         
   AS
   new_field FROM TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, coalesce(
  field_two, field_three, 
  [100, 200, 300][ordinal(range_bucket(field_one, ['A','B','C']))]
  ) as new_field
from your_table
```

or with a little refactoring

```
with map as (
  select ['A','B','C'] find, [100, 200, 300] match
)
select t.*, coalesce(
  field_two, field_three, 
  match[ordinal(range_bucket(field_one, find))]
  ) as new_field
from your_table t, map
```

if applied to sample data in your question - both output

[image]